# Example for Google Translate API

Tags: google-api, google-translate

I want to use the Google Translate API in eclipse and I've checked the Google API website, but there isn't any sample code for the Google Translate API in Java. Can someone provide some and explain how to get started. I have already read the documentation on this API.

Answer (score 0):

https://cloud.google.com/translate/v2/quickstart#JSONP

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Translate API Example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="sourceText">Hello world</div>
    <div id="translation"></div>
    <script>
      function translateText(response) {
        document.getElementById("translation").innerHTML += "<br>" + response.data.translations[0].translatedText;
      }
    </script>
    <script>
      var newScript = document.createElement('script');
      newScript.type = 'text/javascript';
      var sourceText = escape(document.getElementById("sourceText").innerHTML);
      // WARNING: Your API key will be visible in the page source.
      // To prevent misuse, restrict your key to designated domains or use a
      // proxy to hide your key.
      var source = 'https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=YOUR_API_KEY&source=en&target=de&callback=translateText&q=' + sourceText;
      newScript.src = source;

      document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(newScript);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Google Client Libraries](http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-java/0.21.1/index.html) are now the recommended APIs to use. You can now find Java specific [Translation API Client Library](http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-java/0.21.1/apidocs/?com/google/cloud/translate/package-summary.html) examples in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-java).

To report any issues with the new [Java specific Client Libraries](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java), you can directly file an issue on the [GitHub Issue tracker](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=).

Answer (score 0):

you can installe this package for laravel
https://packagist.org/packages/charef/free-translate-api